# execute .innerHTML in a function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, innerhtml

I want to change my HTML before the js code is ended.

I tried to use async functions but i'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this.

```
function wait(ms){
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var end = start;
  while(end < start + ms) {
    end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}

function one() {
  wait(1000);
  document.getElementById("1a").innerHTML = "bla";
}

function two() {
  wait(1000);
  document.getElementById("2b").innerHTML = "blabla";
}

function three() {
  wait(1000);
  document.getElementById("3c").innerHTML = "blablabla";
}

function start() {
  one();
  two();
  three();
} start();
```

the code waits 3 seconds and then update my divs.

I want my code to:

wait 1 second,
update div,
wait 1 second,
update div,
wait 1 second,
update div

Comment: You haven't provided a clear problem statement.

Comment: Javascript uses a single thread, meaning your "wait" doesn't actually work how you think it does

Comment: What is wrong with the given code? Does it work as expected?

Comment: Use intervals.... That wait method does nothing more than just freeze the browser.

Comment: @DerekPollard JavaScript is not asynchronous, per-se. That's why `wait` actually blocks.

Comment: You're reserving the thread with the blocking code, and browser doesn't get a chance to render the changed HTML. That's why you see only the last set `innerHTML`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yep, used the wrong words; it's still early here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

### Using a Function

I made this function which makes it easy to supply an array of objects you want to update.

```
/* 
  timed_elemet_updates(array, int)
  `elements` should be an array of objects which contains the
  ID and HTML you want to update.
*/
function timed_element_updates(elements, seconds) {
      var element = elements.shift();
      document.getElementById(element.id).innerHTML = element.html;
      setTimeout(timed_element_updates, (seconds * 1000), elements, seconds);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
function start() {
    var elements = [
        {id: '1a', html: 'bla'},
        {id: '2b', html: 'blabla'},
        {id: '3c', html: 'blablabla'},
    ];
    timed_element_updates(elements, 1);
}
start();
```

This answer is more concise (less repeating lines of code), easier to use (just add more elements to the array), and more reusable (no new function for every element)

### Original Answer

```
function one() {
    document.getElementById("1a").innerHTML = "bla";
    setTimeout(two, 1000);
}

function two() {
    document.getElementById("2b").innerHTML = "blabla";
    setTimeout(three, 1000);
}

function three() {
  document.getElementById("3c").innerHTML = "blablabla";
}

one();
```

This will call function `one()`, then it will call `two()` after 1000 milliseconds (1 second), then it will call `three()` after 1000 milliseconds (1 second).

Comment: @Vx0 No problem, glad that I could help

Comment: @Vx0 I added (what I consider to be) a better solution to my answer.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: Updated my answer as well to add more background information

Answer (score 1):

That's solvable with `Promise`s:

```js
function showTextAfterMS (text, elemSelector, ms) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let elem = document.querySelector(elemSelector);
    if (!elem) {
      return rej(new Error(`Cannot find element by selector: ${elemSelector}`));
    }
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      elem.innerHTML = text;
      res(elem);
    }, ms);
  });
}



showTextAfterMS('bla', '#el1', 1000).
  then(() => showTextAfterMS('blabla', '#el2', 1000)).
  then(() => showTextAfterMS('blablabla', '#el3', 1000));
```

```html
<div id="el1"></div>
<div id="el2"></div>
<div id="el3"></div>
```

You could also do it with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, but my experience is that using `Promise` is a bit more reliable/stable.

To show the first text without delay, just change the first call to `showTextAfterMS` to be `showTextAfterMS('bla', '#el1', 0)`.

**Edit**

The reason why using `Promise`s is the right solution is ultimately rooted in the runtime concepts of JavaScript. In short terms, it is because technically `setTimeout` as well as `setInterval` are both *asynchronous actions*, because they are both handled by the JavaScript *event loop*. A thorough explanation of the event loop and the general concurrency model of JavaScript can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

In short: Every action that has to be performed is pushed to the end of a `Queue` of actions the runtime has to, ... well, run. This way, actions from the UI are processed as well as other actions like timeouts and intervals. The runtime processes these actions step by step, however, they *might need a different time to complete*. That's because the runtime runs-to-completion, which means every action is processed *after* the precious action has been processed completely. Because actions produced by `setTimeout` as well as `setInterval` are placed onto the `Queue`, the amount of milliseconds *isn't the guaranteed time the corresponding functions are called*. It is a *guaranteed minimal amount of time* which elapses before they are being executed. This makes both of them produce *asynchronous actions*.

However, from an *architectural* point of view, what you need is a reliable and scalable way to *sequence asynchronous actions*. That's where `Promise`s come into play.

Hand waving a bit, we can say that we can arrive at the same solution *without* `Promise` by using callback functions, because of the way the event loop works. It already calls *one function at a time*, right? So here is an "equal" solution based on callbacks:

```js
// A "Promise equivalent", setTimeout based function with callbacks
function showTextAfter (ms, text, elemSelector, onComplete, onError) {
  if (typeof ms !== 'number' || isNaN(ms)) {
    return onError(new Error(`MS needs to be number, got: ${ms}`));
  }
  if (typeof text !== 'string') {
    return onError(new Error(`Expected TEXT to be String, got: ${text}`));
  }
  let elem = document.querySelector(elemSelector);
  if (!elem) {
    return onError(new Error(`Cannot find element: ${elemSelector}`));
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    elem.innerHTML = text;
    onComplete(elem);
  }, ms);
}



showTextAfter(1000, 'bla', '#el1', (elem1) => {
  showTextAfter(1000, 'blabla', '#el2', (elem2) => {
    showTextAfter(1000, 'blablabla', '#el3', (elem3) => {
      // do whatever you want with the elements. this example
      // discards them
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="el1"></div>
<div id="el2"></div>
<div id="el3"></div>
```

It works equally well and allows you to chain your actions in a reliable way. The downsides of it are:

- It doen't scale very well. To chain more actions, you need a deeper nesting, because new actions have to be called *inside the success callback function*.
- You have to do that nesting *by hand*. Therefor, the deeper you have to nest, the harder it becomes to keep track of your code flow. That's why people call it the "pyramid of doom". Imagine having to blend in text for 20 elements.
- Look at the signature of it: `showTextAfter :: Number -> String -> String -> Function -> Function -> undefined`. That's a lot of stuff for that measly little function! Wouldn't it be cool to just pass in the first 3 arguments?

We can mitigate the last problem somewhat by returning a new function from the call to `showTextAfter`, which consumes the `onComplete` and `onError` callbacks:

```js
function showTextAfter (ms, text, elemSelector) {
  return function (onComplete, onError) { // <-- this little fellow here is what it's all about
    if (typeof ms !== 'number' || isNaN(ms)) {
      return onError(new Error(`MS needs to be number, got: ${ms}`));
    }
    if (typeof text !== 'string') {
      return onError(new Error(`Expected TEXT to be String, got: ${text}`));
    }
    let elem = document.querySelector(elemSelector);
    if (!elem) {
      return onError(new Error(`Cannot find element: ${elemSelector}`));
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      elem.innerHTML = text;
      onComplete(elem);
    }, ms);
  }
}


const showEl1 = showTextAfter(1000, 'bla', '#el1');
const showEl2 = showTextAfter(1000, 'blabla', '#el2');
const showEl3 = showTextAfter(1000, 'blablabla', '#el3');

showEl1(elem1 => {
  showEl2(elem2 => {
    showEl3(elem3 => {
      // whatever
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="el1"></div>
<div id="el2"></div>
<div id="el3"></div>
```

Yes, that's better. But, it doesn't *really* solve the problem, right?

Don't panic though, because these are exactly the problems `Promise`s solve! They allow you to *sequence asynchronous actions* in a *scalable way* with much easier to track *control flow*. All the problems above can be removed by having a (native) "in place" return value to which you can "chain" other asynchronous steps which will complete "in the future" (meaning they can complete successfully or they can complete with an `Error`). The really smart thing is, that `Promise` allows you to chain the next asynchronous action *without nesting*.

See my initial (a bit altered) answer:

```js
function showTextAfterMS (ms, text, elemSelector) {
  return new Promise((onComplete, onError) => {

    // type checking stuff...

    let elem = document.querySelector(elemSelector);
    setTimeout(() => {
      elem.innerHTML = text;
      onComplete(elem);
    }, ms);
  });
}



showTextAfterMS(1000, 'bla', '#el1'). // <-- no more nesting!
  then(() => showTextAfterMS(1000, 'blabla', '#el2')).
  then(() => showTextAfterMS(1000, 'blablabla', '#el3'));
```

```html
<div id="el1"></div>
<div id="el2"></div>
<div id="el3"></div>
```

Comment: Seems like overkill to me for such a simple thing

Comment: I'd really like to know why this has been downvoted. @GrumpyCrouton "Overkill" is highly depending on your opinion, isn't it? It's a reusable piece of code which perfectly gets the job done, can be chained for `N` elements without having to write more than a single line per element. By looking at your answer, you have to copy and paste 3 lines per element which makes it not very reusable, does it? From this point of view, your solution is overkill, too

Comment: It really depends on if it _needs_ to be reusable, but your function alone is more complicated and uses the same amount of lines of code as mine. `Promise`'s are a much harder concept to grasp than `setTimeout` also. I'm not saying your solution is bad (It's a great solution), and I definitely did not downvote it (In fact, I upvoted it). Though I think your answer would be _much_ better if you explained how `Promise`'s work. Don't worry, mine was downvoted too with no reason posted.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Didn't meant to say you have downvoted it. That's why I placed your name after my initial statement. Sorry for the confusion! About the amount of code: What I meant to say was that your solution grows quicker in code size if the OP want's to show – let's say – 10 text fragments over time. And yes, you are right by saying that `Promise`s are harder to grasp than `setTimeout`/`setInterval`, but they _are_ the right tool for async stuff. Anyway, both solutions get the job done, just in different ways. P. S.: Upvoted yours, because it does what the OP wants :)

Comment: Yeah I think that if the OP needed to show more text fragments, a more reusable solution would be necessary

Comment: Of course. We all **love** abstraction, right? ;) I'd vote it up again if I could!

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `async functions`:

```js
function one() {
  console.log('document.getElementById("1a").innerHTML = "bla";')
}

function two() {
  console.log('document.getElementById("2b").innerHTML = "blabla";')
}

function three() {
  console.log('document.getElementById("3c").innerHTML = "blablabla";')
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {
  await sleep(1000);
  one();
  await sleep(1000);
  two();
  await sleep(1000);
  three();
}

demo();
```

Ref: https://javascript.info/async-await